# Importing, processing, edit and export .tif files in R

Tags: r, export, edit, tiff, raster

I'm working with a .tif image captured from a Sequoia Parrot sensor. I want to do radiometric calibration and export the resulting image in the same format (.tif).

I import the image as a raster, then process with some algorithms and finally try to export as a .tif file but it is impossible to open. The resulting file is 7 MB but the image cannot be viewed.

Here is my script:

```
setwd("/where the images are/")
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="TIF$", full.names=F)
options(digits=20)

for(i in rlist){ 
  data <- raster(i)

meta <- exifr(i, recursive = FALSE, quiet = TRUE, exiftoolargs = NULL)
SM <- meta$SensorModel
SM <- strsplit(SM, ",")[[1]]
A <- as.numeric(SM[1])
B <- as.numeric(SM[2]) 
C <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "", SM[3]) )

Ep <- meta$ExposureTime   ## Epsilon 
f <- meta$FNumber   ## Focus Number
ys <- meta$ISO  ##ISO

I <- f^2*(data-B)/(A*Ep*ys+C)
I <- flip(I,"x")
I <- flip(I,"y")
```

Comment: I would use `calc()` in first `I` computation. Without an example image, I can't help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is original script well indented? With your example image, everything works right.

I made small changes for better understanding:

```
library(raster)
library(exifr)  

setwd("/where the images are/")
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="TIF$", full.names=F)
options(digits=20)

for(i in seq_along(rlist)){ # small change

  data <- raster(rlist[i]) # small change

  meta <- exifr(rlist[i], recursive = FALSE, quiet = TRUE, exiftoolargs = NULL) # small change
  SM <- meta$SensorModel
  SM <- strsplit(SM, ",")[[1]]
  A <- as.numeric(SM[1])
  B <- as.numeric(SM[2]) 
  C <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\.]", "", SM[3]) )

  Ep <- meta$ExposureTime   ## Epsilon 
  f <- meta$FNumber   ## Focus Number
  ys <- meta$ISO  ##ISO

  I <- calc(data,fun = function(x){f^2*(x-B)/(A*Ep*ys+C)}) # small change
  I <- flip(I,"x")
  I <- flip(I,"y")
  print(plot(I))
}
```

[image]